# Why Doesn't my ajax,javascript work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, search

I'm writing a website to search through my python database. The nonjavascript version worked perfectly. But now I want to use ajax so that the page doesn't have to be refreshed. I.e., the results will show up as soon as the search button is clicked. But it don't work (I click the button and nothing happens). Why not???

```
<script language="javascript">
var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
   else
     {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

function getData(){
if(xmlhttp) {
var obj = document.getElementById("search-results");
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?name=i&city=o",true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 &&
    xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    obj.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    }}
xmlhttp.send(null);
  }}
</script>
</head><body>
<form id="search-form" action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick = "getData()">
</form>     
<div id="search-results"></div></body>
```

Comment: run the page with firebug enabled (a plugin) with firefox and post up any errors it shows when you press the button

Comment: You may need to return false inside the event handler

Comment: thanks
i tried firebug and it showed no errors. i tried switching to false, but that didnt work either

Comment: @secretformula - I'm pretty sure that will solve it. I would post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to return false inside your event handler to prevent the default from executing.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is that this is considered a cross domain request and your browser natively blocks such responses. You need to use jsonp for the same.

http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/

you can get an example of your exact problem here: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/GettingStartedJSON (search for Same Origin Policy on the page)

in essence this is what you want:

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?name=i&city=ocallback=jsonCallback";

var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", url);
  script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");

  window.jsonCallback = function(jsonObj) {

  document.body.removeChild(script);
  delete window[callback];
}

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Why does he need to use JSONP if the request is coming from localhost also? Im assuming he is running a local test server

Comment: it doesnt matter if you are communicating on a different port or a sub domain wherever it is the browser doesnt let you.. here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules

Comment: Didn't notice the different port part, my bad

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by changing two things:

1)I changed `xmlhttp.responseXML` to `xmlhttp.responseTEXT` even though my fetched file is written in HTML. Shouldn't it be XML and not TEXT then?

2) the target element was a `<div>`. I changed the target element to a `<p>` and it worked. Does innerHTML not work in `<div>`?